# Mercurial: How to reduce the number of (hidden) heads?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to reduce the number of hidden (obsolete) heads?

I have a repository with ~1500 hidden heads. Apparently this is too many. According to [the HG wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebInIisOnWindows#Troubleshooting):

> If you have a repository with a lot of heads/branches, you can easily exceed this limit.

The solution there doesn't work for me though. Is there a way to reduce the number of hidden heads (without deleting changesets).

The HG wiki on [Pruning Dead Branches](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PruningDeadBranches) doesn't mention hidden / obsolete changesets. Does "1. Closing Branches" (I don't have any *named* branches) or "2. No-Op Merges" still work for hidden (obsolete) heads? Can it be automated for all 1500 hidden heads? How?

Answer (score 1):

> Does "1. Closing Branches" (I don't have any named branches) or "2. No-Op Merges" still work for hidden (obsolete) heads?

Yes and yes.

> Can it be automated for all 1500 hidden heads? How?

Yes, with a shell script. Probably one that iterates over the output of "hg heads".

Comment: Can you demonstrate how to do it for one hidden head?